# Selecting parameter from values of a SQL Query

Tags: sql, parameters, crystal-reports, report

I need to produce a report that selects a set of values from a database table based on a company. I would like the user to be able to select the name of the company from a list of available companies. The companies have 2 associated unique database ID code number. Based on what companies the user selects I need the sql query to pass to the parameter both unique codes to the parameter. 
So, in short, how do I create a sql query that would show the company names and when selecting the company would then select both unique codes based on the company name I select from a single select drop down. Use the value selected from that drop-down list to run the SQL query in the report itself?

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the company name to to your stored proc instead of the two unique codes, then find the codes for the company inside your procedure.

```
CREATE someProc (@Company VARCHAR(100))
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @ID1 INT, @ID2 INT

SELECT @ID1 = someID1, @ID2 = someID2
FROM someDatabase
WHERE companyName=@Company
```

Comment: to JIM what do you mean by "Create someProc" are you referring to a formula or parameter and how would I write that in Crystal. Again thanks for your help.